# Jquery Conflict Using Similar Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Site info:

- PHP 5.5
- Javascript
- Jquery 1.11.3
- Bootstrap

I have a grid system which is currently underdevelopment that I am having an issue with the jquery .slideToggle function. I am new to jQuery so I am sure I have done something wrong but could use some assistance.

What I am attempting to do is have a dialog box slide into view when a grid is either hovered over or clicked on. I need this to work on both desktop and mobile devices.

Currently, I have gotten the hover function to work using the .slideToggle feature of jQuery but when I use the same ID and Class names to repeat the function on a secondary grid entry it opens both dialogs when it should only open one. How do I make is to that it only opens the one dialog relavent to the grid being selected and not all of them using the same ID?

My function is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slide-down").hover(function(){
    $(".slide-down").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slide-down").click(function(){
    $(".slide-down").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slide-up").hover(function(){
    $(".slide-up").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slide-left").hover(function(){
    $(".slide-left").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#slide-right").hover(function(){
    $(".slide-right").slideToggle("fast");
});

});
</script>
```

You can see the page in question at http://web.oru.edu/dev/new-oru/grid-layouts-1.php

Grid Code:

```
<div class="vgrid col-xs-12 vset">
     <div class="grid-section" id="grid-content">
        <div id="v-slide" class="vgrid-block vgrid29">
            <div class="slide-down sl_blue_bg">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
                <p>text goes here. <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="slide-down" >
                <img src="images/img-7.png" width="489" height="322" alt="img"/>
                <span>office of the President</span>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"but when I use the same ID"* .... that is the problem, ID's must be unique in a page

Comment: Trying to manipulate HTML with duplicate IDs is like trying to build a telephone network with duplicate numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ever use unique IDs. Use classes or some other css selector to apply common functionality to groups of elements. If the trigger is a parent of the grid box, you could use something like:

```
$('.slide-down-trigger').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('.slide-down').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

To select only the relevant grid. Alternatively, you could try using jQuery's built in `closest` method, which will target only the closest element to the trigger.

```
$('.slide-down-trigger').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.slide-down').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**EDIT**

Following further information from the OP, to target the previous element, you should use the `.prev()` method.

eg

HTML

`<div class="slide-down"></div>`
`<a href="#" class="slide-down-trigger">Trigger</a>`

JS

```
$('.slide-down-trigger').hover(function() {
  $(this).prev('.slide-down').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: I tried both of these options and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it just isnt working... 

My hover ID is on the <a> tag and the div that appears is above that in the code. If this is not how I should lay this out, please advise? Again, I am new to jQuery so I am experimenting here and have gotten this far but am stuck now so feel free to point out the errors in my ways.

I am using similar IDs because I couldnt get the hover command to activate on the class alone but if there is a better way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Added to answer following more info from OP

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly from [this link about jQuery's hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2)

Your code should look like

```
$("#slide-right").hover(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle("fast"); 
});
```

As selecting ".slide-right" selects everything that matches .slide-right, whereas selecting this only selects the element hover was triggered from.

Comment: I tried both of these options and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it just isnt working... 

My hover ID is on the <a> tag and the div that appears is above that in the code. If this is not how I should lay this out, please advise? Again, I am new to jQuery so I am experimenting here and have gotten this far but am stuck now so feel free to point out the errors in my ways.

I am using similar IDs because I couldnt get the hover command to activate on the class alone but if there is a better way to do it please let me know.